Is wearing a Fanny pack considered carrying
According to Halacha, is wearing a fanny pack considered carrying or no? So on Shabbat would it be permitted according to Halacha for a Jew to wear a Fanny pack between different domains or no? Is the Din different if it has items in it or no?

If it has items in it then you are at least carrying the items. No worse than a pocket

See H. Shabboth 12:12-13.

See Peninei Halakha [Wearing Clothes Is Not Considered Carrying]  https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-21-10/ (partial extract below)
"One may put on his clothes, shoes, and hat, and then enter a reshut ha-rabim, because clothes are secondary to one’s body. As long as one is wearing them, they do not have independent status but are viewed as part of his body. Thus, he is not viewed as carrying them."
The OP uses the phrase "wearing a fanny pack." Unless I am mistaken a fanny pack is not generally regarded as an item of clothing and so is not "worn" and accordingly would be considered to be carried just as a bag would be regarded as carried. Items within a fanny pack cannot be considered to be worn and will always be regarded as carried, just as items in a pocket in clothing are regarded as carried (as @Double AA says in his comment above).
